# FlatList item doesn't update when I setState()

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm building multiple select modal. When user press the item, the item should be marked as 'Checked'.

**Problem** I added/removed id from id arrays. When I open and check modal, it doesn't show 'Check' sign. But when I close and open the modal again, it shows 'Check' Sign.

[image]

To keep track of selected items, I defined the items in the modal component's state.

```
  state = {
    selectedSeasonIds: this.props.selectedSeasonIds,
   }
```

Here is react-native-modal which I use to show modal on the screen

```
<Modal
      isVisible={isSelectorVisible}
      onBackdropPress = {() => this.props.hideSelector()}>
      <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
          <FlatList
              style={styles.root}
              data={this.props.items}
              ItemSeparatorComponent={this._renderSeparator}
              keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
              renderItem={this._renderItemForMultiple}/>
      </View>
</Modal>
```

This is render function for each item

```
_renderItemForMultiple = ({item}) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.itemStyle}
        onPress={() => {this._handleMultipleItemPress(item.id)}}>
        <RkText>{item.value}</RkText>
        { this._renderCheck(item.id) }   <<< Here is the problem
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
```

When user clicks the item, FlatList's item calls `_handleMultipleitemPress`

```
  _handleMultipleItemPress = (id) => {
    let { selectionType } = this.props;
    let { selectedSeasonIds, selectedSizeIds, selectedColorIds } = this.state;
    if(selectionType===2) {
      if(_.includes(this.state.selectedSeasonIds, id)) {
        let newSelectedSeasonIds = _.filter(this.state.selectedSeasonIds, (curObject) => {
            return curObject !== id;
        });
        this.setState({selectedSeasonIds : newSelectedSeasonIds});
      } else {
        let newSelectedSeasonIds = [...this.state.selectedSeasonIds, id];
        this.setState({selectedSeasonIds : newSelectedSeasonIds});
      }
    }
    // season Select Action
    this.props.seasonSelectAction(id);
  }
```

**Problem** We added/removed id from id arrays. When I open and check modal, it doesn't show 'Check' sign. But when I close and open the modal again, it shows 'Check' Sign.

Somehow the modal is not rendered even eventhough we `setState` in `renderCheck()`. Why is it happening? And How can I fix it?

```
  _renderCheck = (id) => {
    let { selectionType, selectedSeasonIds, selectedSizeIds, selectedColorIds } = this.props;
    if(selectionType===2) {
      if(_.includes(this.state.selectedSeasonIds, id)) {
        return (<RkText>Check </RkText>);
      }
    } 
    return (<RkText> </RkText>);
  }
```

Any other advice will be also appreciated! Thanks for reading this post.

**UPDATE** I debugged with code and when I press the item, it doesn't go through `_renderItemForMultiple`. I think it's because I didn't define a param for `_renderItemForMultiple`. How can I pass item to its param? Any idea?

Comment: I am bit busy with other things, I like to help you but can't discuss now, if you can provide working demo of this code, i  can debug it faster.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me on this problem. However I couldn't make the running plankr :( But here is good news, I debugged the code line by line and I found `_renderItemForMultiple` is not rendered when I setState. Why is it not rendering?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even though your state changes, you're not passing it to `<FlatList>`, so its props don't change.  Its `shouldComponentUpdate` method returns `false` when none its props change.  As the docs state:

> By passing `extraData={this.state}` to `FlatList` we make sure `FlatList` itself will re-render when the `state.selected` changes. Without setting this prop, `FlatList` would not know it needs to re-render any items because it is also a `PureComponent` and the prop comparison will not show any changes.

So you need to pass `extraData={this.state}` to `FlatList`.

Comment: EXACTLY. I figured this out before you posted though. I was answering my own question but you posted early. Thanks!!

Comment: vote up my question too. This may be really helpful for others